# ExtJs - Binding to multiple fields based on one combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, combobox, binding

I am new to ExtJs so I am sorry if this question is vague, I will try to explain to the best of my ability.

I have a store set up as follows

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.ValveSystemStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.valveSystem',
    fields: [
        'SystemId',
        'EquipRef',
        'Type'
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: 'MyApp.Direct.GetSystems'
    }
});
```

My Model

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.ValveSystem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    field: [
        { name: 'SystemId', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Type', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'EquipRef', type: 'string' }
    ],
    idProperty: 'SystemId',
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        api: {
            read: 'MyApp.Direct.GetValveSystems'
        },
        paramOrder: 'id'
    }
});
```

And my ViewModel

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.SystemViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.store.ValveSystemStore',
        'MyApp.model.ValveSystem'
    ],
    alias: 'viewmodel.SystemViewModel',
    stores: {
        systemStore: Ext.create('MyApp.store.ValveSystemStore', {
            model: 'MyApp.model.ValveSystem',
        })
    }
});
```

I have a combo box on "TopPanel" that is populated with a list of the `EquipRef` fields shown in my store. I have a panel below it with a text field for `EquipRef` and `Type`. When I select an `EquipRef` from the combobox, it appears in it's corresponding text field. So far, I have a bind that links the `EquipRef` combobox with its text box, however I cannot figure out how to get `type` to also populate its textbox.

Top panel combobox code

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    width: 200,
    fieldLabel: 'Equip Ref',
    editable: true,
    store: {
        type: 'valveSystem',
        autoLoad: true
    },
    queryMode: 'remote',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    displayField: 'EquipRef',
    bind: '{EquipRef}'

}
```

Bottom panel text field code

```
items: [
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Equip Ref',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        width: 240,
        id: 'equipRef',
        bind: '{EquipRef}', // --> works, textfield populated
        editable: false 
    },
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Type',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'type', 
        bind: '{Type}', // -----> this does not work
        editable: false
    }
]
```

I know this may be an amateur question, I have done research on binding and MVVM architecture but something is going over my head here. Thanks abunch!